# Cursor not moving to originial spot pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

My current code looks like this:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener

mouse = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == Button.right:
        placeX = x
        placeY = y
        mouse.position = (placeX, placeY) # Doesn't work. Why?


with Listener(
        on_click=on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

My goal is to put the cursor back to its original position after the right mouse button is released. When I was testing it, nothing happened. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Doesn't work. Why?

Your current implemented logic looks like this:
On mouse click, if it is the right button (regardless of whether it is pressed or released), store the current mouse coordinates in `placeX` and `placeY`, and immediately move the mouse to that location.

Not very efficient as the mouse was already in this location.

## How to fix?

### Check if the mouse is released or not

```py
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        ...  # remember the position
    else:
        ...  # return to position
```

### Check mouse button

```py
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button != Button.right:
        return  # we don't care

    if pressed:
        ...  # remember the position
    else:
        ...  # return to position
```

### Save original position

```py
# in case the mouse was pressed and not released when starting the program
original_position = mouse.position

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button != Button.right:
        return  # we don't care

    global original_position 

    if pressed:
        original_position = mouse.position  # remember the position
    else:
        mouse.position = original_position  # return to position
```

We use the keyword `global` here so that we can later change the value of a global variable.

### Enjoy

:)

### Alternative

Note that I usually think of `global` as a code smell, so here's a nicer and slightly more advanced solution with a class:

```py
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener

mouse = Controller()


class Mover:
    def __init__(self, original_position=mouse.position):
        self.original_position = original_position

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if button != Button.right:
            return  # we don't care

        if pressed:
            self.original_position = mouse.position  # remember the position
        else:
            mouse.position = self.original_position  # return to position


mover = Mover()

with Listener(
        on_click=mover.on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: @NewUser if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)